# Problems with raster to point operation in QGis 2.18.17

Tags: qgis, python, esri-ascii-raster, raster-to-point

I tried to make points of IDW or Kriging interpolation.  From point csv-file I made .asc raster file, then I tried to make "raster value to points".At first QGIS wrote me about the error:

> ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-35: ordinal not in
>   range(128) See log for more detail

I try to find my files and directories with names with non-English language. Then I try to write in python console:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

QGIS makes .prj file and then close "raster value to points" window without making shapefile.

Tell me please how solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Only English letters and numbers should be used in file paths and names. There should be no spaces anywhere.

Withal, the algorithm creates temporary files that are placed in your System-user folder.
For example, for a user named **USER**:
C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/...

Therefore, you should work under an account that does not have letters other than English and does not have spaces.
I encountered this problem with the "raster value to points" algorithm and solved it by creating an additional ("English") account.
Probably, it is the source of your issues.